# Preserving commit history when moving from one repo to another

Tags: git

There are two repos: SMALL and BIG.

SMALL was created independently of BIG, but they both have the exact same directory structure and files (just the content is different).

BIG is basically made up similar SMALLs (think submodules - I need to edit only a specific directory, not work on the entire repo)

Directory structure for BIG:

> apps/
>     ... folder-one
>     ... folder-two
>     libs/
>     bunch of project-specific files

SMALL:

> apps/
>     ... folder-three
>     libs/
>     bunch of project-specific files

Inside `apps/`, each folder corresponds to a submodule. My SMALL repo has the exact same directory structure, but I don't want to merge everything. Only the folder-three in `apps/`. **Is it possible?**

Problem is, when the project was assigned to me at my workplace, we didn't quite decide where would SMALL be integrated (there were two BIG candidates). Which is why I created a personal repo temporarily.

Now that it's time to integrated, I don't want to simple copy-paste my folder into the BIG repo. I would prefer to preserve my commit history, but push **only** the relevant folder/files into the BIG repo.

#### What I've tried:

- `git pull BIG --allow-unrelated-histories` into the SMALL repo, but that deleted folder-three (the one I want BIG to have)
- I've looked at [filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), but I'm not quite sure if it fits my use-case. If this is the solution, can someone clarify? If it isn't, what would you suggest? (you can assume every file in SMALL except the ones present in folder-three are irrelevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge without committing, then clean up the paths you don't want before you complete the merge.

```
git merge --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories SMALL/master
git reset -- . ':!apps/folder-three/*'
git checkout -- . ':!apps/folder-three/*'
git clean -df
git add .
git commit
```

In order:

1. Merge the two histories, but do not commit yet
2. Reset everything except folder-three. This first includes all folders with `.`, then excludes one path with `:!<pathspec>`. See [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec)
3. Undo all unstaged changes outside folder-three, same method as previous step
4. Remove untracked files and folders. `-d` includes directories, `-f` forces removal. Staged files inside folder-three won't be affected by this.
5. Now add all remaining unstaged changes
6. And commit

The only advantage of this over filter-branch (which would otherwise be cleaner), would be that you can avoid rewriting the history.

If you make a mistake prior to committing, you can `git merge --abort`. If after the merge you don't like the result, you can `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to go back to pre-merge state.

Comment: Where do I merge? In BIG? Running the merge command gives a "not something we can merge" console output

Comment: My answer assumed you had already added the small repository as a remote in the big one, like `git remote add small <URL>`, then `git fetch small`. If you’ve already added small as a remote, you just merge `small/master`, replacing small with whatever the name is of the remote you added. Yes you merge in big

Comment: I did add the remote to small. But I forgot the fetch after that. Let me run these commands and see if they solve my problem